# Spring boot + Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, spring-boot

Still new to spring boot and we are asked to authenticate a user using the companies active directory. I have researched Ldap and spring security, but most examples show using a created file. Just looking for a quick run down of how to set it up for the login page to hit our active directory.

Comment: is it helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/26872236/5132539 ?

Comment: We have it working. What is your specific question? I think the last comment already gives you a good start.

Comment: Not at work right now and I know its hard to tell whats wrong with no code, but had an example up and we kept getting Bad credentials, with multiple different ways. Is there a GENERAL issue to this?