# LDAP Authentication with Spring - getting PartialResultException

Tags: spring, ldap

I am following [this article](https://www.levvel.io/blog/RESTful-API-Security-&-LDAP-Authentication-with-Spring) on setting LDAP Authentication with Spring
Now I can login to the application, but I get this exception:

```
Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); nested exception is javax.naming.PartialResultException: 
Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name 'DC=XEROX,DC=AD,DC=XEROX,DC=com'
Caused by: javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2917) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2891) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1846) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1769) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

according to other [articles I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791654/partialresultexception-when-authenticating-with-spring-security-and-javaconfig/26872236#26872236), I need to set the referral to follow,  setReferral("follow");

But I am not sure where to add this to this code:

```
String completeUrl = new StringBuffer(this.url).append(":")
                    .append(this.port)
                    .append("/")
                    .append(this.contextRoot)
                    .toString();

            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userSearchFilter(userSearchFilter)
                    .userDnPatterns(userDnPatterns)
                    .contextSource()
                    .url(completeUrl)
                    .managerDn(managerDn)
                    .managerPassword(managerPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own contextSource, something like:

```
@Bean("internalLdapContextSource")
public LdapContextSource getLdapContextSource() {
    String ldapUrl = env.getProperty("ldap.server");
    String managerDn = env.getProperty("ldap.manager.distinguished.name");
    String managerPassword = env.getProperty("ldap.manager.password");
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl);
    contextSource.setUserDn(managerDn);
    contextSource.setPassword(managerPassword);
    Map<String, Object> baseEnvironmentProperties = new HashMap<>();
    baseEnvironmentProperties.put("java.naming.referral", "follow");
    contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(baseEnvironmentProperties);
    return contextSource;
}
```

You can use **setBaseEnvironmentProperties** method as shown in the sample or **setReferral** ( both works fine ).

Finally use 
    .contextSource(getLdapContextSource())